# I need to reset the terminal write head, without clearing characters

Tags: terminal

The thing I want to do sometimes happens as a bug. I want to clear my bash terminal, but have the previous characters stay as ghost characters - or whatever, as long as you can see them, but they're not actually there.

I've googled a lot, but cannot find anything.

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using? "Bash terminal" is not a thing; bash is just one of the programs that can run inside a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really clear on what you're asking, but if you're just trying to move the cursor back to the upper left corner (without erasing anything), many terminals support the following escape sequence:

```c
fputs("\033[1;1H", stdout);  // C
```

or

```bash
printf '\e[1;1H'  # bash
```